# Update Nested Dictionary from SQL Query within a Loop

Tags: python

I am trying to populate a dictionary to be used later in a loop that is generated from a SQL query of a system table in another loop. When I had only 2 dimensions in the nested dictionary I did not have a problem, but I needed to add 2 more dimensions and I'm not sure how to populate the dictionary from that.

I have 4 dimensions: studio, node (this number may vary by studio), volume (this is the "path" in the query and also may vary), and storage (this again may vary). I would like the output similar to the following:

`{'studio1': {u'v_studio1_node0001': {u'/vertica/data': {u'CATALOG': n,
                                                            u'DATA,TEMP': n},
                                        u'/vertica/data2': {u'DATA,TEMP': n}},
                 u'v_studio1_node0002': {u'/vertica/data': {u'CATALOG': n,
                                                            u'DATA,TEMP': n},
                                        u'/vertica/data2': {u'DATA,TEMP': n}},
                 u'v_studio1_node0003': {u'/vertica/data': {u'CATALOG': n,
                                                            u'DATA,TEMP': n},
                                        u'/vertica/data2': {u'DATA,TEMP': n}}},
     'studio2': {u'v_studio2_node0001': {u'/vertica/data': {u'CATALOG': n,
                                                            u'DATA,TEMP': n}},
                 u'v_studio2_node0002': {u'/vertica/data': {u'CATALOG': n,
                                                            u'DATA,TEMP': n}}}}`

The following has just the studio and node_name which were the 2 dimensions that I have working in the dictionary `studio_node_names`. I added `studio_node_volume` which I would like to populate with all 4 dimensions then the numeric as the value.

```
#Create dictionary to hold studio names and node names for each studio to be used for creating alarms
studio_node_names = {}

# Create dictionary to hold studio names, node names, volume, and storage for each studio to be used for creating alarms
#studio_node_volume = {}

for connection_blob in STUDIO_CONNECTION_INFO:
    studio = connection_blob['studio']
    connection_info = connection_blob['connection_info']

    try:
        conn = vertica_connect(connection_info)

        # Query the v_monitor tables to get metrics for alarms
        try:
            disk_usage_result = conn.query("select su.node_name, su.path, du.storage_usage, su.usage_percent from v_monitor.storage_usage su join v_monitor.disk_storage du on INSTR(CONCAT(du.storage_path, '/'), CONCAT(su.path, '/'), 1, 1) = 1 and du.node_name = su.node_name where su.path not in('', '/') and (du.storage_usage = 'CATALOG' or du.storage_usage like '%DATA%')")
        except (BotoClientError, BotoServerError, Exception) as e:
            print "ERROR: Vertica Query exception message"

        # Update the metrics derived from the row data returned from the query "disk_usage_result".
        for row in disk_usage_result.rows:

            # Update the cluster Disk Usage metric.
            disk_usage = row['usage_percent']
            node_name = row['node_name']
            #volume = row['path']
            #storage = row['storage_usage']

            if studio_node_names.get(studio):  # For looping over to create DiskUsage alarms later
                studio_node_names[studio].append(node_name)
            else:
                studio_node_names[studio] = [node_name]

    except (BotoClientError, BotoServerError, Exception) as e:
        print "ERROR: Vertica Connection exception message"
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()

print "INFO: Done checks of Vertica instances."

for connection_blob in STUDIO_CONNECTION_INFO:
    studio = connection_blob['studio']

    # Create the DiskUsage alarm.
    for node_name in studio_node_names[studio]:

    try:
        # Alarm code here
    except (BotoClientError, BotoServerError, Exception) as e:
        print "ERROR: DiskUsage create_alarm exception message"
```

The other `connection_blob` loop for "Create DiskUsage Alarms" is where I will be looping over the `studio_node_volume` to create alarms for each studio, node, volume, storage combo.

Comment: Could { studio: [nod,volume,storage] } be possible?

Comment: Possibly. I am new to Python so I a lot of the stuff I have tried is a bit trial and error since I am still in the learning process.

Comment: you could set studio as dict key than the value is list contain all other elements you wanted

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to create the dictionary I expected using the following:

    `if studio not in studio_node_volume:
        studio_node_volume[studio] = {}
    if node_name not in studio_node_volume[studio]:
        studio_node_volume[studio][node_name] = {}
    if volume not in studio_node_volume[studio][node_name]:
        studio_node_volume[studio][node_name][volume] = {}
    if storage not in studio_node_volume[studio][node_name][volume]:
        studio_node_volume[studio][node_name][volume][storage] = {}
        studio_node_volume[studio][node_name][volume][storage] = disk_usage`

Answer (score 0):

I actually created the dictionary another way so I could initialize keys. I put the following before the `for connection_blob in STUDIO_CONNECTION_INFO:` loop:

```
class D(dict): 
    def __missing__(self, key): 
        result = self[key] = D() 
        return result 

studio_node_volume = D()
```

Then under the `for row in disk_usage_result.rows:' loop and after the four variables for the rows I have:

```
        studio_node_volume[studio]
        studio_node_volume[studio][node_name][volume]
        studio_node_volume[studio][node_name][volume][storage]
        studio_node_volume[studio][node_name][volume][storage] = disk_usage
```